Forcing amd64 image platform on arm64 host (docker compose)
I am attempting to use "docker-compose up" on the command line to run a simulator using noVNC but am getting the error "image with reference [my image] was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/amd64, actual: linux/arm64/v8". I've seen some solutions for docker run and docker build, but docker-compose doesn't seem to take the platform argument on the command line. Any ideas? Does it have anything to do with the Ubuntu virtual machine that's acting as the host in this case?
I have added the "--platform" flag within the Dockerfile, added "platform: linux/amd64" inside docker-compose.yaml, and even attempted to set the default platform using "export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64", but the error keeps coming back.

You can make it using args
ARG plateform=linux/amd64
FROM --platform=$plateform debian:bookworm-slim

and put in your docker-compose.yml
services:
  your_service:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        plateform: "<your_plateform>"


neither of these worked for me!

You should declare platform with linux/amd64 inside of service. For sample can use this form my project.
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: be
    platform: linux/amd64
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 5001
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app/


This is one of the things I tried (as you can see in the original post), and it did not work.

add platform under servcie seems worked for me. But I worried is the choice of platform might be automatically detected by the system. What if i use linux/arm64 yml to build on asurecloud with linux/amd64?
